# I can not get the img to move up into my header before the header text and also be responsive with the page

Tags: html, css

I want to move the img to be before the logo text and for it to be responsive. I can manage to position it but then it wont move when I resize the page.

```css
header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 1600px;
}

.header-content {
  display: inline-block;
  display: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  max-height: 58px;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #220901;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: #582F0E;
  Font-Family: 'Cormorant Garamond', Serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: none;
  Font-Family: 'Fira Sans', Sans-Serif;
  Font-Size: 12px;
  color: #c2c5aa;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-height: 73px;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 330px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding-left: 400px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 4px;
  padding-top: -10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #BB4D00;
  Font-Family: 'Cormorant Garamond', Serif;
}
```

```html
<section class="header-container">
  <header>
    <div class="header-content">
      <h2 class="logo">Treat YourShelf Books</h2>
      <p><i>A good book really hits the plot.</i> </p>
      <img src="/img/logo2.png" alt="Treat YourShelf-BookStore Logo" />
      </div>
  </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and position the image where you want

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-content {
 display: flex
 Flex: column
 ...
 }
```

For stacked arrangement...

Comment: I dont see it as being misspeleld

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For the image to be on top of the text you just have to put your image tag on top of the desired one, moreover a lot of things in your code don't necessarily serve a purpose or can be done in a more optimal way (I commented what I thought was not necessary).
The flex-wrap property will take care of the responsiveness of the page, meaning that the elements will go one under the other if there is no more space.
Good evening and good luck in your learning!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  //top: 0;
  //left: 0;
  //right: 0;
  min-width: 1600px;
}

.header-content {
  //display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  //position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  //max-height: 80px;
  //height: 80px;
  //justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #220901;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: #582F0E;
  Font-Family: 'Cormorant Garamond', Serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  //margin: 0;
  //padding: 0;
  //padding-left: 15px;
  border: none;
  Font-Family: 'Fira Sans', Sans-Serif;
  Font-Size: 12px;
  color: #c2c5aa;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-height: 73px;
  //display: flex;
  //padding-left: 330px;
  //box-sizing: content-box;
  //padding-left: 400px;
}

h2 {
  //margin-top: 7px;
  //margin-bottom: 0;
  //margin-right: 4px;
  //padding-top: -10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #BB4D00;
  Font-Family: 'Cormorant Garamond', Serif;
}
```

```html
<section /*class="header-container" */>
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    <img src="/img/logo2.png" alt="Treat YourShelf-BookStore Logo" />
    <h2 class="logo">Treat YourShelf Books</h2>
    <p>A good book really hits the plot.</p>
    <p>You can manually ajust the height or you can let the display flex do it for you .</p>
    <p>no matter how many elements you add </p>
  </div>
</header>
</section>
```

Comment: Thats not responsive at all.